How to return a response of an audio file AND an array of data at the same time?
please pardon me, I am quite new to fastAPI and coding in general.
In my backend, I am using fastAPI. I have an audio, audio_data and a data, data that I need to send back to client side as a response. How can I do this?
@app.post('/chat')   
async def post_audio(file: UploadFile = File(...), history: str = Form(...)):

   ...   

   audio_data = getAudio()   
   data = ['transcribed_reply','transcribed_response']

   return Response(content=audio_data, media_type="audio/mpeg")



I am able to send the audio back by itself with
   return Response(content=audio_output, media_type="audio/mpeg")

and Client Side I would do
   const res = await fetch(...)
   const blob = await res.blob()
   ...

but I'm not sure if there is a way to send both back at the same time?
*** edit ***
I did find that I can just return a response like this
return Response(content=audio_output, media_type="audio/mpeg"), data

and in my client side, i do
const res = await fetch(...)
const resObj = await res.json()
audio = resObj[0]
data = resObj[1]

However, Im not sure how to create a blob out of audio this way, or how to use it for that matter.

You can send additional data in Headers:

headers = {"X-something": "value", "X-something-else": "value"}
return Response(content=audio_output, media_type="audio/mpeg", headers=headers)



I did try this, but for some reason in my client side application I was not able to read from the header the values I inputted. Will try to provide more specifics on why tomorrow when I give it another shot, but thanks for the comment, atleast this tells me I'm on the right path
